Does Terraform apply destroy manually created resources
We do have done lot of manual network configuration such as vpc peering, routing table changes, all those changes done by manually after initial network configuration has been setup using Terraform. Recently I have done new ALB related changes using Terraform, does Terraform apply destroy manually created resources, because I can only see my ALB changes only going to apply when I tested using terraform plan. seemed to be all manual changes not identified by terraform. I’m ok as far as Terraform plan not going to destroy the manually created configuration.
Apply My ALB changes using terraform apply without destroy manually created resources.

Terraform mutates resources which are there is state files, which implies which in your terraform manifest (.tf files). Although it may complaint if the dependent resource already exists and you are creating again. On deletion it may complain dependent resource cant be deleted.


because I can only see my ALB changes only going to apply when I tested using terraform plan

If the terraform plan output doesn't say it is going to delete something, then no, it is not going to delete anything. There are no "hidden" things Terraform is going to do without showing them in the terraform plan output.
It sounds like the things you have done manually were creating or modifying resources that do not exist in your Terraform configuration.
